# Used update manager and now can't boot up

Tags: boot, update-manager

I started my machine after a few weeks of not using it. Update manager wanted to perform a load of updates so I said OK. it was huge, took an hour to download.it

Now I can't boot up! I get to the log in screen where it asks for my password, I enter the password and the screen goes black, flickers and it just re-boots, coming back to the password screen.

How can I fix this, please?

Ubuntu 16.4LTS
Acer Aspire Revo Nettop with Nvidia Graphics & Intel Atom processor.

Answer (score 0):

I think Nvidia drivers have caused the issue.

issue this :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

this is how to completely purge the nvidia driver and use the open source nounveau.

Comment: thanks Kaylee. I'll give that a shot. My main issue is with my graphics driver. Any advice on that?

Comment: Hi Kaylee, Thanks for that, I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Good luck ! I hope it can be useful for you.

Comment: Hi Kaylee, I think I've done the removal of the nvidia and replaced with nounveau, but the graphics are now horrible. Looks all low res and to big for the screen, is that what you would have expected?

Comment: Hi Kevin, Don't worry about that we will fix it, if you can now login normally, because this is the issue you've asked about, I mean the login loop, when you enter the password, the screen goes black then the password screen comes back again.

Comment: let me know if u can login normally now after removing Nvidia.

Comment: Hi Kaylee, Yes I can log in normally when the Nvidia stuff has been purged, what now?

Comment: I did follow someone else's advice and use synaptic package manager to install a nvidia-340 driver, but i get the same result... the log in screen loop.

Comment: so, trying again. on the sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf, I get a connot remove /etc/x11/xorg.con no sure file or directory??

Comment: Hi @KevinWilson , I guess it's too late to help, I'm sorry about that, I was so busy last time.  well u shouldn't reinstall Nvidia drivers since its the cause of problem, but not all versions I guess the problem is the latest version you've updated.
so issue the following steps to :

first remove again that drivers and then reinstall previous version of Nvidia :

`sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

`sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

`echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`

Comment: hi Kaylee, are you still able to help me?

Comment: Hey, yes if I can help you, why not ?

Comment: Great! Thanks once again. You may remember that you told me how to install the standard drivers and the hi-res Nvidia driver was causing the PC to crash and re-start. Well, I followed your instructions successfully, but the graphics are too low res and horrible. So much so, that most of the windows are off-screen and can't be seen.

Comment: Any further suggesyions that may help me?

Answer (score 0):

remove again that drivers and then reinstall previous version of Nvidia :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

then reboot and try to log in normally even with horrible graphics. and go to  synaptic or whatever to find any previous version of Nvidia then install it .

Comment: hello, I'm still struggling to get up and running with the original graphics drivers. Can anyone help me?